# c# Converting from string to special type - "an explicit conversion exists"

Tags: c#

```
Outputs.RunParams.RunAlgorithm = Convert.ChangeType(AlgString,typeof(RunAlgorithmConstants));
```

I'm trying to set a Run Parameter for a program to a specific value, but the AlgString is a string and I need it to be of the type RunAlgorithmConstants. AlgString being a string is a result of converting from type RunAlgorithmConstants to string directly in a previous script, saving it to a text file, reading from that text file, and setting the text to AlgString.

When I run this code I get this error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'RunAlgorithmConstants'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The namespace is fine. I could write

```
if (AlgString.Equals("Example1"))
{
Outputs.RunParams.RunAlgorithm = RunAlgorithmConstants.Example1
}
```

for every possible value that RunAlgorithmConstants could be but I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Edit:

```
int LineNumber = Inputs.LineNumber;


var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Inputs.LoadLocation);


string line = lines[LineNumber];


{char[] delimiterChars = {','};


  string[] words = line.Split(delimiterChars);
  words[30] = AlgString
```

Comment: Your error message says an explicit conversion exists, have you tried explicitly casting it?

Comment: Also: RunAlgorithmConstants is a type defined under the program in the namespace

Comment: What the hell is in AlgString?  "Two slices of bolognia and a slice of cheese please"?  Why should a string be converted magically into a RunAlgorithmConstants?

Comment: Just tried explicitly casting it, gave me an Error saying it cannot convert string to RunAlgorithmConstants.

Comment: AlgString is a direct conversion from  a RunAlgorithmConstants value to string so that it could be saved in a text file for records. Now, I'm loading lines from that text file so I can use it as input for my program to replicate the conditions that the program was previously in.

Comment: The result of `Convert.ChangeType` is an instance the target type upcast to `object`. You need to downcast the `object` instance to its target type, as the compiler is suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

[Enum.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for:

```
Outputs.RunParams.RunAlgorithm = (RunAlgorithmConstants) Enum.Parse(typeof(RunAlgorithmConstants), AlgString);
```

Comment: It's giving me the same error as before. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Is the ```type``` of your ```Outputs.RunParams.RunAlgorithm``` an ```object```?  It would be useful for you to show the declarations of ```AlgString``` and your enum and probably ```RunAlgorithm```.

Comment: Edited in above

The enumeration is built into the program I am using.